# eclipse is displaying all lowercase els "l" as uppercase "L"; not changing them just displaying them. Can I get it to stop "helping" me?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse 3.7.2 appears to be "helping" me distinguish lower case "L"s from the number one by displaying them as upper case...while retaining them as actually lower case.

It is not doing this for method names but it is for method invocations.

So if I have a method called "doPortfolio" it leaves it alone.
When I call the method it displays it as "foo = doPortfoLio", but when I control-click on "doPortfoLio" I go to "doPortfolio".

Can I turn off this helpful behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is interestingly bizarre :)

I just tested this and this seems to be working as expected for me :

[image]

Does not seem probable, but is it possible that you have two versions of that method, one with a small i.e. : `doPortfolio` and the other with a captial one i.e. : `doPortfoLio` ?

As far as I know, Eclipse should not be doing what you are experiencing !

Comment: I can type the lower case name and watch as Eclipse "corrects" it to the upper case L.