# Eclipse Disable Auto Correct

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, ide

After manually typing a method name that begins with a lower case letter e.g. load() or

```
     OpcPackage xlsxPkg = OpcPackage.load(excelFile);
```

Eclipse 'magically' switches the first letter to upper case e.g. Load() or

```
    OpcPackage xlsxPkg = OpcPackage.Load(excelFile);
```

This is causing a compile error. I looked around the Preferences (e.g. Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced) but couldn't spot the right option to disable this feature.How do I disable this auto correct feature?
(Please don't suggest I change the method name as it is a third party jar).

Thank you,
Josh

Comment: I've never encountered this behavior. Are you certain that jar is on your build path?

Comment: Yes. I added it. Also, the method shows up in the suggestion list (in lower case). When I select it, it is added correctly (lower case) and then magically changes to upper case.

Comment: Does ctrl-space (code completion) work? Have you tried restarting eclipse with `eclipse -clean`?

Comment: Elliott - Yes, code completion works and then the l goes upper case. I did an eclipse.exe -clean and the problem persists. TY for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a little dated, but I had the same problem in late 2017 with Eclipse Oxygen.  Here is how I resolved it:  Go to Eclipse preferences->Java->Content Assist.  Then uncheck "Insert single proposals automatically."  This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue, follow the steps below

```
Eclipse preferences->Java->Content Assist.
```

Enable the checkbox with the label

> Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In the Window > Preferences menu, you can search for spell checking (located in General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling) and there you can edit your spell checking options.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried unchecking the 'Enable Spell Checking' option (,restarted Eclipse) and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847483/eclipse-is-displaying-all-lowercase-els-l-as-uppercase-l-not-changing-them) shows someone else had a similar issue with Eclipse 3.7.2, though no solution was posted. What version of Eclipse are you using?

Is it possible you have conflicting jars?

I wish I could have added this as a comment, but alas, I don't have 50 reputation points.

Comment: Nice find wrt that similar issue. I am using Mars.1 Release (4.5.1). I don't believe I have conflicting jars.