# how do disable "auto correct" in eclipse java

Tags: java, autocomplete

when i try to write a new variable, String for example, it auto select a name with the variable type.
for example:

```
String str="hello world"
```

instead:

```
String strString="hello world"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Disable Auto Correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521576/eclipse-disable-auto-correct)

Comment: what version is this? This is the very first time I've ever seen this

Comment: This sould answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521576/eclipse-disable-auto-correct

Comment: the version is 2019-09

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to press `Esc` before you press `Space`.

If you want to turn off from settings:

> Window->Preferences->Java->Editor ->Content Assist-> Advanced On top
>   box uncheck: "Java Non-Type Proposals", "Java Proposals" and "Java
>   Proposals (Task-Focused)".

Generally its good practice to postfix datatype at the end of each variable. Personally I follow this approach. You may also rethink before turning off this feature.